# Eliminar numero con awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed, log

tengo el siguiente problema de la uni:

```
Hacer un script que accedar al syslog (/var/log/syslog) y filtre todas las líneas que contengan la
palabra “error” o “fail”, ya sea sola o con algo más (por ejemplo, “failed” o “errors”), minúsculas o
mayúsculas (debe aceptar “ERROR”, “Error”, “error”).
Luego, cada registro deberá tener el siguiente formato:
DIA / MES – HORA – PROCESO (sin el número de pid) – mensaje
No debe incluir el nombre de la máquina ni el número de pid, el ancho de columnas debe ser
consistente.
La salida deberá enviarse a un nuevo archivo llamado errores.log con un encabezado que explique
el formato. 
En caso de ya existir un archivo con ese nombre, deberá generar un archivo que se llame
AÑOMESDIAerrores.log (ejemplo, 20201027errores.log)
```

Estoy trabado intentando (" ***Luego, cada registro deberá tener el siguiente formato:
DIA / MES – HORA – PROCESO (sin el número de pid) – mensaje. No debe incluir el nombre de la máquina ni el número de pid, el ancho de columnas debe ser
consistente.*** ") para hacerlo deduje: ("***awk '{ print $2 "" $1 "-" $3 "-" $5 }' /var/log/syslog*** ")

Pero no se como borrar el pid ni ajustar el ancho de las columnas.
Alguien sabe como proseguir, o hacerlo?
Gracias por su tiempo

**Edito:** Primero quiere que elimine de /var/log/syslog las lineas que tengan la palabra error, esto lo hice con grep -iv 'error', luego quiere que de lo que me quedó saque las columnas que representan DIA / MES – HORA – PROCESO – mensaje.
Eso lo hice con awk '{ print $2 "/" $1 "-" $3 "-" $5}'. Pero no se como quitarle el numero del pid ni como igualar todas las columnas para que quede bonito como me piden.

**Edito:** Osea, como uso awk para imprimir la columna $5 sin lo que hay entre corchetes ejemplo: proseso[1525] >> proseso.
Tengo hasta ahora esto: grep -iv 'error' /var/log/syslog | awk '{ print $2 "/" $1 "-" $3 "-" $5 "-" }' Me falta también imprimir el "mensaje"

Comment: Me gustaría ayudarte, pero no entiendo la redacción de tu publicación. El formato y todo es un tanto confuso.

Comment: Gracias por responder, primero quiere que elimine de /var/log/syslog las lineas que tengan la palabra error, esto lo hice con grep -iv 'error', luego quiere que de lo que me quedó saque las columnas que representan DIA / MES – HORA – PROCESO – mensaje. eso lo hice con awk '{ print $2 "/" $1 "-" $3 "-" $5}'. Pero no se como quitarle el numero del pid ni como igualar todas las columnas para que quede bonito como me piden.

Comment: Osea, como uso awk para imprimir la columna $5 sin lo que hay entre corchetes ejemplo: proseso[1525] >> proseso

Comment: da por favor a [edit] para añadir los detalles relevantes en la publicación, pues en los comentarios no se ve bien.